# none filesystem in WSL got large disk space

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, disk-usage, windows-subsystem-for-linux

By running the following command, a path (/`usr/lib/wsl/drivers`) with `none` filesystem type appears:

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /mnt/wsl
none            477G  441G   36G  93% /usr/lib/wsl/drivers
none             16G     0   16G   0% /usr/lib/wsl/lib
/dev/sdc       1007G  279G  678G  30% /
none             16G   96K   16G   1% /mnt/wslg
rootfs           16G  1.9M   16G   1% /init
none             16G  992K   16G   1% /run
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/user
```

What can be done to reduce the amount of space it got?

Answer (score 2):

The `/usr/lib/wsl/drivers` happens to show the underlying Windows disk volume size. If you look from Windows at the available disk space for your `C:` drive you will see that it directly matches the amount shown for `/usr/lib/wsl/drivers` in WSL - and also for the mounted `/mnt/c` that you've not shown in your question.

Because it's a virtual filesystem of type `none` (or for `/mnt/c` it's type `drvfs`) you can be reassured that the space is not exclusively allocated to WSL, but it's simply available should you need to use it. There is no need to try and reduce the space available.